# Excel Online Cannot Match Multiple References At A Time

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula, excel-online

I am trying to use INDEX MATCH with 2 matches across two different sheets however multivariable matching only works on Excel Desktop and not Excel Online. I need this to work on the online version because of the auto-sync with a Microsoft form. I made a simpler example for the purposes of this question.
I tried different ways of referencing sheets in the formula but I believe the syntax in the picture is correct.

Sheet1!A2 should match with rows Sheet2!A1 and Sheet2!A4;

Sheet1!B2 should match with rows Sheet2!B2 and Sheet!B4;

The MATCH formula should output 4

Comment: Post few sample data and desired output.

Comment: I use excel online and I have used intensively `INDEX`, `MATCH` or `XMATCH`. That is not the issue.

Comment: @DavidLeal how do you know that is not the issue? Did you post this question? If so where is the image?

Comment: @SolarMike I was trying to confirm the OP there is no issue with those functions in excel web. Based in my experience. The question didn’t provide too much details, so I can’t say more. I didn’t post the question. Let’s see once more details are provided what else we can suggest.